# How to search text within text in nested if condition?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2007

I am trying to categorize a list text which sometimes requires an exact text match and sometimes part of the text, depending on that I want to categorize these text.

I have already tried the combination of `if` and `find` function but it's not working in case of third `if` statement.

```
=IF(G2="SILVER", "SILVER",IF(G2="COPPER", "COPPER",IF(FIND("BLACK METAL",G2),"COPPER",IF(G2="GUN METAL", "ANT. SILVER", IF(FIND("GUN METAL",G2), "ANT. SILVER", IF(G2="ANT. SILVER", "ANT. SILVER", IF(FIND("ANT. SILVER", G2), "ANT. SILVER",  IF(FIND("MATTE SILVET", G2), "MATTE SILVER", IF(FIND("ROSE GOLD", G2), "ROSE GOLD",   IF(FIND("TIN", G2), "TIN", IF(FIND("WHITE DUSTED ZINK", G2), "TIN", IF(FIND("DARK DUSTED ZINK", G2), "ZINK", IF(G2="ZINK", "ZINK",  IF(FIND("ANT. BRASS", G2), "DYEING",  IF(FIND("SUCCESS 63", G2), "DYEING", IF(FIND("WORN BRASS", G2), "DYEING",   "NONE"))))))))))))))))
```

[finish category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIUVf.jpg)

since I want to add further category I prefer the use of `vlookup` or something,  if that is possible.

Comment: FIND doesn’t return true/false, it returns the position of the found text or what is essentially an error when not found. Adjust your logic around that.

Comment: FIND() will give a numeric result if the text exists so use the logical test of FIND() > 0

Comment: Would you please include a sample of data to be categorized?

Comment: basically, I want to check what is the text inside the g2 cell, 
if g2 = "python" then return "python" or
if g2 = "Django" then return "python" or
if g2 contains "snake" then return "animal" or
return "not categorized"
here g2 have 3 different values, 1. python 2. Django python 3. python snake
for 1 it should return "python", for 2 "python", and for 3 "animal"
hope the question is clear...
note: I need to check at least 10 different values, where some value will be an exact match and other will be a partial match or keyword match.
thanks

Comment: Would you please include in the question (no picture pls) at least the 10 real values with the corresponding category to be assigned to each, I have an answer ready, but would like to test against a realistic sample, in order to ensure it works, before posting it, just don't want to receive changes and tuning after it's posted. thanks.

Comment: let's say I'm checking A2 cell,
silver silver
ant. silver

Comment: let's say I'm checking A2 cell,

A2 cell value      -      expected result

silver    =    silver
matte silver    =    matte silver
ant. silver with white paint     =     ant. silver
tin     =     tin
**white dusted zinc    =    tin**
zinc    =    zinc
**dark dusted zinc = zink**
silver with blue paint    =    silver

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted an If(Match()) combination?

```
=IF(MATCH("*"&"Silver"&"*",G2,0)>=1,"Silver",0)
```

The match function will try to locate the word "Silver" in any of the cells you are referencing, which in this case is G2. If it locates "Ant. Silver" in that cell, it will return "Silver". Obviously this can be built upon which I can do for you if you find this of any use.

Failing this. Try

```
=INDEX(A1:A5,MATCH("*"&G2&"*",A1:A5,0),0)
```

Where your different values are within A1 - A5

Comment: Thanks,
but I want to check multiple conditions where sometimes I need an exact match and sometimes need a partial match. can that be done?if i remove the wildcard "*" will it search for an exact match?
could you please show me a demo...

Comment: Check my edit with index match. This will search for multiple conditions and will produce exact matches along with partial matches if applicable. Actually.... just saw 1 of your latest comments, this wouldn't help with that!